# "Even-though" in Russian language

Tags: одним-словом

What would be the accurate translation for "**Even though**"?

I found "**даже если**" and "**даже когда**" and in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-russian/even_2?q=even%20though) (English- Russian)  "**несмотря на то что**". So, I am a little bit confused about the term that I have to use.

For example:

> **Even though** he is a smart man he did that mistake.
>
> **Even though** he was around he didn't come to say hello.

Comment: At the start of a sentence (without an "if"), "несмотря на то, что" is preferable.

Answer (score 7):

> **Even though** he is a smart man he did that mistake. - **Несмотря на то,
>   что** он умён ... / **Хоть** он **и** умён, ...
>
> **Even though** he was around he didn't come to say hello. - **Несмотря на то,** что он был поблизости ... / **Хоть** он **и** был поблизости ...

**даже когда** means **even when** and is appropriate when there's temporary aspect involved:

> He didn't work out **even when** he was young, much less now when he's 70
>   - Он не занимался физкультурой, **даже когда** был молод, а теперь, когда ему 70, и подавно.

**даже если** - **even if**, when there's a condition:

> **Even if** he showers her with gifts and jewelry she still won't marry
>   him - **Даже если** он будет осыпать её подарками и украшениями, она всё
>   равно не пойдёт за него замуж.

Comment: BTW, more natural here would be to adjust tense - "он сделал ошибку, хотя и БЫЛ умён" - "he made a mistake despite he WAS smart". IF we aim at literaturally smooth text as the outcome, not подстрочник

Comment: @Arioch or more accurately *despite of being smart/despite the fact that he was*, but adjustment of tense isn't necessary if a person is considered generally smart and if they're still alive, in any case the English sentence was provided by the OP

Comment: That is why I explicitly said it depends upon the required translation type. The literary one (подстрочник, word by word) or a "literature" one, which is basically a retelling of the story. When retelling you use constructs and patterns natural for target language. And that is why tense adjustment might get introduced, to make the translated=retold text more Russian, more natural.